# How to get string value from query parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, mongoose, axios

I'm trying to get the string value within a class-object variable called question5. I'm trying to access this variable like so in the front-end.

```js
axios.get("http://localhost:3001/users/questionaire/?getquestion5=question5")
  .then((res) => console.log(res.data))
```

Also, this is how it looks inside of the object in the js file.

```js
const [answerslist, setAnswerslist] = useState(
      {
        question1: "",
        question2: "",
        question3: "",
        question4: "",
        question5: "",
        question6: "",
        question7: "",
        question8: ""
        
      }
    )
```

However, when queried and log onto the console from the backend it literally just logs the string 'question5.' In other words, the string is literally just question5 not the text being added to it.

```js
router.route('/questionaire').get((req, res) =>{
    console.log(req.query.getquestion5)
    User.find({email: req.query.getquestion5}, function (err, docs){
        if(docs){
            console.log("Email exist")
            console.log(`${req.query.getquestion5}`);
            console.log(docs)
        }
        else{
            console.log(req.query.getquestion5)
            console.log("Email doesnt exist")
          
        }
    }).clone().catch(function(err){console.log(err)})
  
})
```

Any reason why this might be the case?

Comment: `"question5"` is the literal string value you encoded in the request URL `"http://localhost:3001/users/questionaire/?getquestion5=question5"`. What else could the `getquestion5` queryString parameter's value possibly be?

Comment: It would more helpful to us if you also update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what it is trying to do, or how it's doing what it currently does.

Comment: @Phil I tried req.query.answerslist.question5 as the params and it literally just gave me that as a string value.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your backend code.

Comment: Sorry, there was no sarcasm, and no, I couldn't have possibly known what you meant when the only context was the code you provided and you asking why the value was what it was. I could *guess* that *maybe* you didn't intend to use the string literal `"question5"`, but guessing what you intended isn't what we're here for. Sorry if my initial response was a little blunt though.

Comment: @JustinYoungTech you said _"I tried req.query.answerslist.question5"_ which is backend code. Please [edit] your question to show how you're constructing the request with Axios and detail any values that it _should_ be using

Comment: Inputs. `onChange` handlers. These are relevant details that would help inform you and all of us why the request was made the way it was. I don't want to double pile on with Phil, but until we see what the frontend code is doing we can't really provide any further help. We can't diagnose/debug code we can't see. This entire "conversation" has really gone sideways.

Comment: Probably some confusion due to your misuse of `\`\`\`` [code fences](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). The code needs to start on the line after `\`\`\`` otherwise you can't see the first line. I've fixed it up for you now but it's always good to check over your question to make sure it looks how you intended

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to send the `answerlist.question5` state value in the query string `getquestion5` parameter, try using [Axios' `params` config option](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config)

> `params` are the URL parameters to be sent with the request
> Must be a plain object or a URLSearchParams object
> NOTE: params that are null or undefined are not rendered in the URL.

```js
axios.get("http://localhost:3001/users/questionaire", {
  params: {
    getquestion5: answerslist.question5
  }
});
```

You'd then receive whatever value was in state at the time the request was made into the `req.query.getquestion5` property.

---

Using `params` is preferable to interpolating strings directly into the URL since it will automatically [URL-encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) values that otherwise would not be valid. The equivalent safety measure would look like this...

```js
axios.get(
  `http://localhost:3001/users/questionaire?getquestion5=${encodeURIComponent(answerslist.question5)}`
);
```

which gets unmaintainable with more parameters.